# Webpack hot loading for React project not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, flowtype

Because I prefer to use Flow. So I migrated Typescript based project to Flow based one.
I also edited the configuration of the webpack and added plugins for Flow.
But webpack hot loading is not working.

[my Flow+React project](https://github.com/neosarchizo/react-nodegui-starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, the uppermost component (App) has to be a class in order for the hot-reloading to work

[Hot loading for Flow not working](https://github.com/nodegui/react-nodegui-starter/issues/31)